# error with Gulp / Bower

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower

I'm trying to run gulp, but I get a lot of errors.

First, I ran npm install, and I had to wait like 30 min to finish.

Then, I ran gulp, and I get:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/senosiain$ gulp
[21:19:34] Using gulpfile ~/senosiain/gulpfile.js
[21:19:34] Starting 'default'...
[21:19:34] Starting 'task'...
[21:19:34] Starting 'bower'...
[21:19:34] Using cwd:  /home/vagrant/senosiain
[21:19:34] Using bower dir:  ./bower_components
[21:19:35] 'bower' errored after 653 ms
[21:19:35] Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/senosiain/node_modules/gulp-bower/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
[21:19:35] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'bower'.
[21:19:35] Finished 'task' after 747 ms
[21:19:35] Finished 'default' after 768 ms
```

So, I run

```
npm install mkdirp
```

and it works fine, and then I run gulp, and the same message appear with another lib.

I've been installing like 20 libs like that and I'm tired, and thinking maybe there's 300 of them, so something is wrong....

I also ran bower install

```
npm install gulp -g
npm install (inside folder)
gulp bower ( fails the same way)
```

Any Idea how should I do it not to do it one by one???

Comment: Just a thought. Try clearing the npm cache. `npm cache clean`

Comment: and then what should I do?

Comment: Try again? If you really want to gush it out, clear the cache, delete the `node_modules` folder entirely and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: it worked! Put it as answered please! Tx!!!

Comment: Happy to hear. I added the answer for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the `npm` cache and starting fresh.

`npm cache clean`

Completely delete the `node_modules` folder. Then..

`npm install`